# Kotlin: cannot access enum defined in companion object

Tags: kotlin

According to Kotlin documentation:

> Members of the companion object can be called by using simply the
>   class name as the qualifier.

Why does it not seem to work here?

```
class Foo {
  companion object {
    enum class Type { A, B, C }
  }
}

class Bar {
  val typeA = Foo.Companion.Type.A  // works
  val typeB = Foo.Type.B            // error: "Unresolved reference: Type"
}
```

Comment: Because `Enums` are not actually members of the Companion object. You can achieve what you want by moving your `Type` to the `Foo` class directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparing the two qualified type names, `Foo.Type.A` and `Foo.Companion.Type.A` , the former would rather mean a type declared directly inside the `Foo`'s scope.

The latter form, therefore, is used to disambiguate types declared inside a type from ones declared inside its nested types and object declarations (including the `companion object`).

```
class Foo {
    class Bar // Foo.Bar

    companion object {
        class Bar // Foo.Companion.Bar
    }
    object Baz {
        class Bar // Foo.Baz.Bar
    }
}
```

As [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9241978/pawel) noted, nested types and object declarations are not members and have different resolution rules than those of functions and properties.